# Lock Adding rows with a specific Foreign Key ID on Postgres/SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a tabel similar to this one:

```
PERSON:

id | person_name 

ITEM:

id | name | person_id
```

Items person_id is a FK to person.

I have an operation that add's items in bulk to a person. But I want to make sure no other processes are adding items concurrently to this person without blocking the entire person table.

Is there a way to achieve this in Postgres? And better a the code to accomplish this using Python SQLalchemy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` via `Query.with_for_update`.  Just a warning though you have to be carefully to always lock in the same order and same way or else you can easily lockup your threads. Ie. don't lock table A then lock table B in one area of code and lock table B and then table A in another area of code because it can cause a deadlock.

```py
# Other calls to SELECT FOR UPDATE will BLOCK when they try to lock this person
person = session.query(Person).with_for_update().filter(Person.id == 5).first()

# Update person items here
for item in person.items[0:3]:
    session.delete(item)

session.commit()
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html?highlight=for_update#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.with_for_update

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE

Comment: Thank you very much :) this is just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Just locking the specific person will prevent other sessions from inserting items referencing that person.

```
select * from person where id=? for update
```